# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kind'

Tags: python

I am using SMOTE to oversample as my dataset is imbalanced. I am getting an unexpected argument error. But in the documentation, the kind argument is defined for SMOTE. Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong?

Code :

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
sm = SMOTE(random_state=r_state, sampling_strategy =1,k_neighbors=9,kind='svm')
sdf=sm.fit_resample(x_train,y_train)
```

Error :

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kind'

Comment: Docs don't mention a `kind` parameter. Can you link to the documentation you're using?

Comment: I don't see the `kind` parameter in https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html. What version of the library are you using, and what documentation are you checking?

Comment: Also, as of version 0.6.0, `The parameters m_neighbors, out_step, kind, svm_estimator have been removed from the imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE. #617 by Guillaume Lemaitre.`  https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#id13

Comment: I found it here in example 19 https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/123410/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE

Comment: should I replace ''Kind'' with an other parameter ?

Comment: what command do you use to install imblearn? Does is "pip install imbalanced-learn"?